# Obtener audio de Youtube Live Streaming

Tags: python, youtube

¿Hay alguna forma de obtener SOLO la url de la pista de audio de una emisión en directo de Youtube?

Estoy intentándolo con las librerías de Pafy y Youtube-dl pero solo obtengo archivos mp4, no hay archivos m4a como en el resto de vídeos.

```
streams = video.audiostreams
for a in streams:
    print(a.bitrate, a.extension, a.get_filesize())
```

Esto no devuelve nada.

Hay alguna alternativa? O simplemente Youtube no provee archivos m4a para los directos? Y si este es el motivo... habría alguna forma de conseguirlo?

Alguna idea?

Gracias!

Comment: A decir verdad, no conozco, pero ¿has consultado la documentación? Yo hice esta pequeña prueba: ví en la pestaña "Network" del navegador las peticiones de un streaming. Tengo una URL de ejemplo que obtuve "pero es muy larga" y al copiar y pegar la URL en la barra de navegación devuelve un fragmento de audio "en mp4" de escasos 2-3 segundos. Tu tendrías que "de alguna manera" conocer los parámetros y averiguar cómo generar mas peticiones para descargar esas peticiones y unirlas "si deseas" o procesarlas como deseas.

Comment: Sí que miré la documentación, pero no localicé nada. Revisaré lo que me dices. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

prueba con pytube
https://github.com/nficano/pytube

```
>>> yt = YouTube('http://youtube.co/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0')

>>> yt.streams.all()
 [...
  ...
  ...
 <Stream: itag="278" mime_type="video/webm" res="144p" fps="30fps" vcodec="vp9">,
 <Stream: itag="140" mime_type="audio/mp4" abr="128kbps" acodec="mp4a.40.2">,
 <Stream: itag="171" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="128kbps" acodec="vorbis">,
 <Stream: itag="249" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="50kbps" acodec="opus">,
 <Stream: itag="250" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="70kbps" acodec="opus">,
 <Stream: itag="251" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="160kbps" acodec="opus">]
```